# How can I put a command in the background process after the command has been run?

Tags: background-process

I need to put interactive command (some values are entered from the console and then an infinite loop is running) in the background process. Since I need to enter values, I can't initially run the command in the background. So I want to run the command, enter values and when the loop starts, put it in the background. I can stop the command using Ctrl+Z. But when I run bg, command continues not in the background(the results of the command are displayed on the screen). And after that Ctrl+Z doesn't work.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LbwMkEB4_ZTsDoufIdbOwXVbhrKijfe3/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you be more specific than *"doesn't work correctly"*?

Comment: Ctrl-Z and bg / fg in general works fine ... can you describe your problem. where it .. doesn't work correctly ..

Comment: How do you know that the command does not continue in the background. Please explain what you notice and what you expect to notice for the particular process. It helps if you tell us what process it is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can I see the output of background processes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/662817/why-can-i-see-the-output-of-background-processes)

Answer (score 3):

The way you describe is how you put a process that has been started and "blocks" in the background. That is how it works. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> suspends the process and releases the command prompt. `bg` continues the process in the background.